# csv_read: convert dates to int/boolean

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with a column "graduated" which either shows the date of graduation, or 0 if there is no graduation yet.

df.dtypes return 'object' for this column, I want to turn all the dates into a '1' (indicating that the person in that column graduated). How can I do that ?

Comment: `np.where(df['graducate'].eq('0'), 0, 1)` remember to import numpy as np

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` to convert dates and convert to boolean series. Then, cast it to `int` to get the desired result.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.graduated, errors='coerce').notnull().astype(int)
```